# Convert Microsoft Word documents (.doc/x) into HTML files

Tags: html, css, file-conversion

Does anybody knows of a good application to get it done quickly and efficiently ?

I bought [Word Cleaner](http://www.convertwordtohtml.com/) but the results are merely sufficient and I need to go over all the generated html files to clean tons of useless injected tags like

```
<strong>H</strong><strong>ell</strong><strong>o </strong><em>Wor</em><em>ld</em>
```

Most of the articles displayed on a website I manage are based on documents written on MS Word by people how has little idea of what are margins for or ordered/unordered lists, foot/end notes etc and I cannot make them use something else.

Does anyone has a tip to help me handle those pages more efficiently than going over them to correct and apply my CSS style ?

NB: Just for the record, using "Save as HTML DOC" in Word is faaar worst than Word cleaner

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what me and the team here at work use when bringing MS Word content to HTML:

http://word2cleanhtml.com/

We check all the boxes, paste the code, then convert.

I hope that helps.

Comment: word2clean is indeed a great converter, very clean and exactly what we need. Thanks !

Comment: Very nice, glad I could help!

Answer (score 3):

I think the best solution for this would be using a WYSIWYG editor.
TinyMCE, for example, it's a good one - although i suspect you might need a standalone one.
The usage would be similar to any word-like program, but the output would be straight HTML.
Also, have you tried other word-like programs, as OpenOffice or LibreOffice? The HTML it's not great, as it has lots of inline styling, but from a quick test it looks like it doesn't have the problem of lots of unnecessary tags.

Comment: tinyMCE is great and is what I trying to make THEM use. I've already added more formatting options to help them get what they want to achieve but it's the migration itself from word to *something else* that I'm struggling to achieve and meanwhile I keep receiving .doc files. But thanks anyway, you say openOffice gives good results converting doc to HTML, well I will give it a try.